# Tap passes through UISlider

Tags: ios, objective-c

My UISlider is a subview of a UIView which has a UITapGestureRecognizer. If the slider is tapped or only moved a little bit, the superview detects a tap, which is not what I want.  I tried adding a UITapGestureRecognizer to the slider, but the action isn't called and the superview's tap action is still called. The slider is working, so userInteractionEnabled is already YES.

Is there a way to make a UISlider intercept taps?

Comment: Why would you want a slider to have a tap gesture recogniser? Thats not how a slider would be used by the user.  Is it that you want the slider to work as intended without the tap gesture on your view registering  any taps when the user slides the `UISlider`?

Comment: @JSA986 the sliders tap gesture recognizer is a dummy, which calls an empty method.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out my work-around works, I just didn't do it right.

The solution is to add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the UISlider, which calls an empty method. This intercepts the tap so the superview's tap isn't called.

The reason it didn't work was that I was adding the same UITapGestureRecognizer to multiple UISliders. It has to be a different gesture recognizer on each slider.

Comment: You should accept your own answer as it works perfectly. Thanks!